# Protobuff explicitly callback it's callbacks

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

is it possible to explicitly call one of the callbacks like [ProtoBeforeSerialization] ? from any other classes ? 
I'm trying to force the on deserialization process?

Comment: they are just methods, so... you could just invoke them? do you have a concrete example in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that there are callbacks like:

```
[ProtoBeforeSerialization]
public void FixupStuffBeforeSerialization() {...}

[ProtoAfterSerialization]
public void FixupStuffAfterSerialization() {...}

[ProtoBeforeDeserialization]
public void FixupStuffBeforeDeserialization() {...}

[ProtoAfterDeserialization]
public void FixupStuffAfterDeserialization() {...}
```

then the process to explicitly call one of the callbacks is: to explicitly call one of the callbacks. For example:

```
obj.FixupStuffBeforeDeserialization();
```

If you have something more subtle and nuanced in mind, please do let me know - ideally by providing a concrete example. If the scenario is that you only have `object obj`, and don't know the names of the methods - then you would have to look for them via reflection. For compatibility and comparability with other serializers, this is specified via attributes, not an interface.

But something like:

```
var method = FindMethod<ProtoAfterDeserializationAttribute>(obj);
if(method != null) method.Invoke(obj, null);
```

with:

```
static MethodInfo FindMethod<T>(object obj)
    where T : Attribute
{
    if(obj == null) return null;
    var methods = obj.GetType().GetMethods(
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    return methods.SingleOrDefault(m =>
        Attribute.IsDefined(m, typeof(T)) && m.GetParameters().Length == 0);
}
```

Note that protobuf-net actually supports multiple signatures for these methods, including with context parameters - this should act as a general guide, though.

---

Note that *technically* the rules for choosing the callbacks are more complicated that the above suggests; if you want to know the *actual* method that protobuf-net will be using, then: ask the type-model:

```
var callbacks = RuntimeTypeModel.Default[obj.GetType].Callbacks;
MethodInfo before = callbacks.BeforeDeserialize,
           after = callbacks.AfterDeserialize;
// ...
```

Comment: what If I want to call one of the callbacks of an object that should be first deserialized? should I then make them static ?

Comment: @andre I cannot parse that sentence; can you illustrate with an example?